# When searching for a child node in django admin, would like it to also display the parent org

Tags: python, django, search, parent-child, admin

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YsTh.png) below shows a django admin search page where the parent is authors and the child nodes are books. Currently, when searching for a book in the search box it will only display the book. I would like to also display the parent org when searching. That way if two books had the same name we could what author they were under and determine which is which.

Comment: You can control the searchable fields in admin with `search_fields`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, take our [tour] and see how do I ask a good question [ask].